# How to run Spark Streaming application with Kafka Direct Stream in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am running the program for *Spark* streaming using *Kafka* and getting error. All imports are done and looks resolved without any issue.

I have written few code using *IntelliJ IDEA* and getting an error while running the program for the first time and I am new to *Java* but from *C#* background. So couldn't understand the issue. The *zookeeper* service is started, along with *kafka-server* started and also created a topic called `topicA`. Producer is also ready to stream data but i have problem running code in *IntelliJ* for listening to the queue

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
    "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "group.id" -> "0",
    "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
    "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
  )
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Streaming Application")
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))
  val topics = Array("topicA")
  val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    ssc,
    PreferConsistent,
    Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
  )

  stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    // Get the offset ranges in the RDD
    val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
    for (o <- offsetRanges) {
      println(s"${o.topic} ${o.partition} offsets: ${o.fromOffset} to ${o.untilOffset}")
    }
  }

  ssc.start

  // the above code is printing out topic details every 5 seconds
  // until you stop it.

  ssc.stop(stopSparkContext = false)
}
```

Exception produced is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray overrides final method toBuffer.()Lscala/collection/mutable/Buffer;
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.loadFromSystemProperties(SparkConf.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:57)
at sparkStreamClass$.main(sparkStreamClass.scala:20)
at sparkStreamClass.main(sparkStreamClass.scala)
```

here is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.learnStreaming</groupId>
    <artifactId>sparkProjectArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: It's not possible to debug this as-is. Can you show the whole of the source file that contains the `main` function? Are you using _SBT_, _Maven_, _Gradle_, etc. to retrieve the necessary libraries, configure the compiler, etc. or have you installed them manually? If the former, can you post your build file (e.g. `build.sbt`, `pom.xml`, etc.). Which version of _Scala_ are you using and which version of _Spark_ (the latter must support the former)?

Comment: One guess would be that you are using wrong version of Scala. Unfortunatelly Scala major releases are not binary compatible. So it would really help if you show us your build configuration including all the dependencies

Comment: installed scala version on my system is 2.13 
and spark version is 2.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modified pom.xml and it worked for me !

```
 <properties>
    <spark.version>2.1.0</spark.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

i also meet this problem，it cause by using wrong version of Scala.For example , i define scala2.11.8 in my maven build plugin, but i use scala2.13.So check the pom build scala version and using scala verison in your ide.

Answer (score 0):

We get this issue because of version incompatibility between SCALA and SPARK libraries

I was getting similar error when I had following configuration:
spark-core_2.11 , spark-sql_2.11 , Scala - 2.13

I installed **scala 2.11** in my system and added new Scala SDk libraries to program module and it worked.